# AppData folder missing in terminal from an external Windows HDD

Tags: data-recovery

I had a laptop running Windows that presented some defect and is no longer turning on, though the HD is not faulty (as far as I can understand it).

I also have another laptop running EndlessOS.

I have plugged the old Windows HD, and it automatically mounted. I could copy most of the files I needed, except for the files in the `AppData` folder. When I was using Windows, `%APPDATA%` pointed to `c:\users\<username>\AppData`; however that folder does not seem to exist in the mounted drive.

Are there any specific settings needed during mounting? I tried `ls -a` which should show me hidden files, also to no avail. Just to reiterate, I was able to copy another folder (e.g. `/Users/<username>/Documents`), just not `AppData`.

Thanks in advance for any help or direction where I can find more information.

Answer (score 1):

Filesystem corruption? I can see it on Windows 7/10 partitions just fine. https://i.stack.imgur.com/En7XB.png

No additional mount options are required to see the directory: it's available by default, there's nothing special about it. Boot into Windows again and check it's there.

You could try:

- disabling fast startup: https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10
- Running `chkdsk.exe c:` in an elevated `cmd.exe` prompt (this requires a full reboot)

Comment: I was afraid this could be corruption. All other folders are fine though, which is really strange. Thanks for the reply!